Black login/logout screen on Kubuntu 22.04
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XZbGhMJtnn/
This had me going for several days. I thought the following boot message error was the problem: [      1.159596] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19). I tried reinstalling the AMD drivers several times thinking the black boot up screen was a graphics driver problem. The system was booting, but the login screen is a black screen. When I enter my password, the desktop boots up normally. I tried loading a new splash screen and a new login screen. This did not change anything. When I choose Logout from the power down menu, the screen goes black. Entering my password logs me back into the desktop. If I boot in rescue mode, I see the new login screen and splash screen.
Can any these boot log errors from dmesg.1 be the cause?
[    0.021213] kernel: Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-27-generic", will be passed to user space.
[    5.102286] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=817 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102508] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=819 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102693] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=809 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102754] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=824 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102795] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/haveged" pid=823 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102845] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=810 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102850] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=810 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102933] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=814 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.102936] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.128:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=814 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.760816] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.788:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1057 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[    5.840131] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.868:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1134 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.869351] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713246462.896:44): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1134 comm="apparmor_parser"

